# Passive voice form of 'I think, therefore I am'

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

I'm curious about the passive voice forms (if any) of the sentences,

> I am

and

> I think, therefore I am.

Comment: ***I am defeated*** looks pretty "passive" to me. What definition of "passive" are you thinking of?

Comment: No passive forms in your sentences according to the generally accepted understanding of the word [passive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive-forms) in grammar.

Comment: ACTIVE *A friend **gave** him a **book*** PASSIVE *A book **was given** to him* OR *He was given a book [by his friend]* You need a transitive verb to construct a passive construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only transitive verbs can be made passive in English.

*Think* can be transitive, but here it is not, so has no passive.

The copula *am* has no passive.

Answer (score 0):

> Thoughts were processed by him, therefor he exists.

This is, I believe, as close as one can come to a passive form of

> I think therefore I am.

which is famously an English translation of the Latin

> Cogito ergo sum

and has been influenced by Latin Grammar.

The above passive form is a much weaker statement.

There simply is no passive form of "I am".

Answer (score -1):

I, an idea, am thought... (Very weird, but can be constructed.)

...therefore, uh, I am. (No passive voice construction here.)

Comment: It is not very clear what you are saying. You could edit to explain.